# How to better isolate a floor with carpet?

Tags: installation, carpet

I am going to put a carpet on a room. This room is on a ground floor and it's actualy cold (I can feel the cold on the ground).

Is there some material that I can put between the carpet and  the floor to provide better isolation?

Comment: When you say isolation do you mean insulation, or are you trying to convey the idea of a vapor barrier?

Answer (score 3):

When you install carpet you're first supposed to put down a carpet padding. This is available in a number of different materials including urethane foam and rubber though most commonly these days I see a recycled urethane product. It's main purpose is to prolong the life of the carpet by absorbing some of the shock of being walked on. It also provides a softer feel underfoot as well as some insulation.

If you want to increase the R value of the carpet padding, choose the densest and thickest padding recommended by the manufacturer for the carpet you're buying.

The Carpet Cushion Council (apparently it's a thing) has some example [R-values for carpet padding](http://www.carpetcushion.org/r-value.cfm) listed on its website.

Answer (score 1):

carpet makes it a good insulator in itself. However, a thick, insulating layer of underlay the carpet will further improve its insulating qualities.